# How to cast a VB.net generic type instance to a COM type?

Tags: vb.net

I have a number of functions that look basically like…

```
 Public Function Keys() As Dictionary(Of Integer, myData).KeyCollection
```

I'm trying to expose this class to COM so I can use it in Excel, but VS complains that…

```
 Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type instance in a signature. Generic code may not be exported to COM.
```

I think this means I have to copy this to a type that can be exported to COM, I suspect a SAFEARRAY of strings?

Anyone have an example code of this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expose generic types to COM, it has no support for it whatsoever.  The reason that Dictionary doesn't have the [ComVisible(true)] attribute.  Somewhat intuitively obvious, languages like C++, scripting languages like VBScript or Javascript, VB6 and VBA, etc, don't know beans about .NET generics.  Only a .NET program can ever use it, you don't need COM interop for that.

If you want to expose a dictionary then you'll need to create your own or simply fall back to the olden Hashtable.  Which is [ComVisible], your type library will automatically include mscorlib.tlb

Comment: It's not the dictionary, it's an array of strings representing the dictionary keys. Any sort of "array of strings" or "list of strings" or anything like that should work.

Comment: Well, of course you can expose an array of strings.  ArrayList is fine too.  As long as it is not KeyCollection, that's generic.  Clearly I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: Ok, so is there an easy way to turn a KeyCollection into an ArrayList? Looping is fine, but I'd prefer something already in the API.

Comment: Well, sure, it's but a sliver of code: arrlist.AddRange(dict.Keys).  That does *not* make it cheap.  Design your ComVisible class to be as compatible as possible with the client code.  Copying dictionaries should always be avoided.